# Visualizing effectively transport transit lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, overlapping-features, visualisation, transportation

I have a shapefile that contain bus lines. You can see a screenshot below:

[image]

I would like to visualize the lines in a more understandable way since there are a lot of overlapping sections.

I have tried to experiment with the `offset` of the lines.

[image]

However, this is a bit tricky since new overlapping sections are created.

Do you have a better recommendation? My goal is just to present them in a more understandable and clear way.

Comment: If that is all your data maybe you can manually digitize a [transit map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transit_map)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the ["Geometry Generator"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator) to create additional lines where several lines overlap. I have 3 lines in 3 colors with an attribute `no` with values 1, 2 and 3. The lines are [exploded](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#explode-lines).

I start with the red line (no 1) and create an additional symbol layer for each line that shares the same segments. Create an expression that only returns those segments from lines 2 and 3 that overlap, then apply an offset to that line and style it accordingly (color).

I used this expression to get the segments of line 2 that overlap line 1:

```
if (
    no=1,
    overlay_equals(
        @layer, 
        $geometry, 
        filter:=no=2
    )[0],
    ''
)
```

[image]