# QGIS Geometry Generator, How can I move Line symbols by a y value

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator

I have a lot of lines on top of each other in QGIS, and I would like to show them kind of like London Tube Underground Map.

My main aim is to move each symbol vertically down by a certain amount so line1 would move 1m south; then line2 would move 2m south and so on.

I have tried offset but the lines are made up of a lot of segments running left right and right left. this causes the offset not to work.

Comment: Hello, can you show an example of what you achieved and how your problem characterizes

Comment: may be this will answer your question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/426595/87346