# Selecting geographically identical (underlying) line segments and offset them in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, geometry, overlapping-features

My project has three lines representing three routes along town streets. All three routes lie on the same street for part of their lengths; two of them lie on the same street for another part of their lengths. (The lines have been offset for visibility, but in fact, I do not want them to offset at all, except as described below.)

Possibly key information: each line is in its own separate shapefile layer.

[image]

I want to display the routes offset from one another *only where their geographic positions coincide* - I do *not* want to offset line features along their entire length.

After some reading online, I think I need to select the line segments that over- or under-lie each other and offset just those segments. An alternative: select those line segments that overlie/underlie and create new line segments that are parallel and offset by some specified distance.

I have tried to follow this suggestion: [Visualizing effectively transport transit lines in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/424890/visualizing-effectively-transport-transit-lines-in-qgis) (that is, following Answer 1 by @Babel). I do not get any results - no segments are selected, and no new features are created. Messing around with Layer Properties > Symbology > Single Symbol > Line > Geometry Generator has not led me anywhere; I don't know enough to make this system work for me.

How to do this?

Comment: Pay attention to this thread : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304352/identifying-features-with-duplicate-geometry-in-qgis

Comment: @Taras - Thank you kindly for your suggestion.
I tried following the steps in each answer in that thread and had no success. However, I have begun to think that I need to have all three routes (line features) in ONE shapefile together, not in three separate shapefiles. Then these methods might work.