# Uploading transit data to QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, color, transportation, transit

I'm in QGIS and I've got a map of all the bus routes. The only problem is that they are all one layer, and I can't color each route individually. There isn't a property (as far as I can tell) that can separate them. How can I color different lines differently?

I went to get an image example in New York but it just crashed. It's just quickOSM bus lines in Manhattan.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose inside of the layer, each route is a separate line (feature). So you can apply categorized layer Styling with `$id` as source. Like this, you get a separate color for each line.

See this tutorial for details : [QGIS Training Manual | 3. Module: Classifying Vector Data](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/classification.html#basic-fa-classifying-nominal-data).

Also pay attention to threads like this one: [Visualizing effectively transport transit lines in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/424890/visualizing-effectively-transport-transit-lines-in-qgis).