How to visualizing lines along a mutual segment in parallel in QGIS?
I'm trying to create a similar visualization to this (from Google Maps) in QGIS:

The aim is to visualize each (train) line separately despite them following the exact same route in reality. Ideally, without the spaces between shown above.
I've already set up the lines and identified the mutual segment they follow using Intersection, but haven't found a way to effectively visualize it. I've tried using blending (Symbology -> Blending Mode -> Multiply) as well playing with layer draw order, but the lines are exactly on top of each other along those mutual segments. I'd like to avoid changing the route geometry for this visualization, a tedious process in its own.
Is there another symbology technique that could work here, using QGIS 3.36? Open to other software solutions.


this is a tricky problem, there are already several question dealing with this that you can search (like this one : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/424890/visualizing-effectively-transport-transit-lines-in-qgis) but ultimately I think the only viable solution is to create (or at last finish) this kind map in a graphic software as there are to many edge case to find a satisfying fully automated solution...

Another solution : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239129/shifting-display-of-overlapping-lines-in-qgis/268556#268556

Thanks! Far more complex than it appears...
